# OpenLayers feature Object array to localStorage

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to save an array consisting of multiple features via localStorage.

```
var featureArray=[];
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  if (feature) {
    featureArray.push(feature.values_);
  }
});

function saveFeatures() {
  localStorage.setItem('features', featureArray);
}
saveFeatures();
```

Via console `console.log(featureArray);` looks fine, but when I try to load them via `localStorage.getItem('features')` the output (after two clicks) is something like:

> [object Object],[object Object]

But I actually want the values behind this structure to be saved:

[image]

I tried JSON.stringify(featureArray) but that throws the error

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/ytc26fju/3/ (hover over the dot, then save and then try loading with the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Don't fully understand why, but a feature Object had a circular structure. I had to do:

```
for (i=0;i<featureArray.length;i++) {
  delete featureArray[i].geometry;
}
```